# What is logic behind this

Tags: c#-4.0

You are given an array of elements. Now you need to choose the best index of this array. An index of the array is called best if the special sum of this index is maximum across the special sum of all the other indices.

To calculate the special sum for any index, you pick the first element that is and add it to your sum. Now you pick the next two elements i.e. and add both of them to your sum. Now you will pick the next elements and this continues till the index for which it is possible to pick the elements.

For example:

If our array contains elements and you choose index to be then your special sum is denoted by -
 , beyond this it's not possible to add further elements as the index value will cross the value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is currently hard to understand, particularly as the example looks like it should have sample values in, but they're not present. Additionally, your question is likely to be received more positively if you show how you've already attempted to solve the problem, and give details about what's gone wrong. At the moment this reads like a simple copy/paste of a homework question - it may well not be, but it's in your interest to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: 1) Pick the first element, 2) pick the 1 + 2 firsts elements, 3) pick the 1 + 2 + 3 firsts elements, n) pick the 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1) + n first elements ? Is that the special sum of indexes?